# DB2 Table C UDF DBINFO and SQLUDF_TRAIL_ARGS

Tags: c, db2

I am currently implementing a C Table UDF and I want to make use of both SQLUDF_CALL_T (it is included in the SQLUDF_TRAIL_ARGS) and the structure dbinfo. Is this possible?

If yes, how can this be done? I am asking because when I include both of the structures as arguments, none of them returns reasonable values.

Thank you,
Nick

P.S.: I can provide more information/sample code if requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I figured it myself, I will provide the answer below:

The correct way to provide bot `DBINFO` and `SQLUDF_TRAIL_ARGS` to a C UDF is to define them as arguments to the C UDF. For instance, if you write your UDF in C code (let's say `sample_c_udf`), it has to be something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlca.h>
#include <sqludf.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void SQL_API_FN sample_c_udf(
        SQLUDF_VARCHAR *input,
        SQLUDF_BIGINT *outputVal,
        SQLUDF_SMALLINT *inputNullInd,
        SQLUDF_SMALLINT *outInd,
        SQLUDF_TRAIL_ARGS_ALL,
        SQLUDF_DBINFO* dbinfo
)
{
    (... your code here...)
}
```

As strange as it may sound, the order in which you define `SQLUDF_TRAIL_ARGS_ALL` and `dbinfo` matters. According to DB2's Documentation, `dbinfo` should always be after your `SQLUDF_TRAIL_ARGS_ALL` in the argument's list.

After you type your UDF's code, then you can "register" it in your database by executing a SQL script similar to the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample_c_udf 
( INPUT VARCHAR(32) )
RETURNS BIGINT  
EXTERNAL NAME 'your_compiled_code_file_name!sample_c_udf' 
LANGUAGE C 
PARAMETER STYLE DB2SQL 
NOT FENCED THREADSAFE 
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT 
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
NO SQL 
NO EXTERNAL ACTION 
SCRATCHPAD 32000 
FINAL CALL 
DBINFO 
ALLOW PARALLEL;
```

Remember, to always define the `DBINFO` directiver, otherwise your UDF is not going to work.

Thank you.